# How to handle a data transfer object with multiple feature data slices in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm new to ngrx and need help getting in the "redux" mindset. I'm learning from this demo: [Heroes App with ngrx](https://github.com/johnpapa/ngrx-demo). My question is how to handle an api response that contains multiple feature states. Coming from a non-ngrx world I think in terms of "dto's" where, to reduce http requests, the api returns several collections in one response.

For example if an endpoint in the api in the Heroes example returned a structure like:

```
{
    heroes: [...list of hero objects],
    villains: [...list of villain objects]
}
```

Should this type of cross-cutting update go in a root reducer? I'm I going at this all wrong?

Any help is appreciated - Hans

Comment: Why are you learning ngrx?

Comment: I worked with react and redux briefly and liked the unidirectional data flow concept. I work in angular now so when I saw ngrx I figured it was worth learning.

Comment: Learn RxJs. Then learn how to build Angular services with observables. You can build unidirectional data flow without ngrx.

Comment: We have a hater... To offset that opinion a bit, ngrx is absolutely great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the action in both reducers (heroes and villains).

When you return from the service, you can dispatch a `Fetch Success` action with `villains` and `heroes` in the payload of the action. Because an action is dispatched to all reducers, you can pluck the info that you need in both reducers and update the state accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Curious if you've seen a sample that does something like this. I've searched without luck. I'm really digging NgRx!